# sql and table design to reserve from resource pool

Tags: sql

ok, we have N messaging queues and they are a pool and we want to allow servers to reserve 1 messaging queue.

I am thinking table

- id (primary key)
- reservation job name (nullable if available)

Then, I have 1 row for each queue.  The question is can I do one sql query that looks for 1 available queue and updates it to my job name.

```
update jobname='myjob' where reservation jobname= null
```

would update all the rows.  How to update max 1 row?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: is it sql-server or mysql or something else?

Comment: you have a space too between "reservation" and "jobname" that I assume isnt in your version

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table SET Jobname = 'Something' 
      WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table WHERE Jobname IS NULL)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

**I think a better solution would be to have 3 Tables**:

*Since no RDBMS was specified, this assumes MySQL but could be adapted in general to others.*

[image: Simple Queue Reservation ERD]

This structure has a lot of small but valuable features including:

- Separation of Jobs from a Job reservation (what if there are no
  available queues?) Retrys can start with job with oldest `createdAt`
- Queue status allows prepping a Queue or taking one
  offline by changing its status
- queue_job provides audit trail and historic record of queue reservations by job

**How to use it**

A job can reserve a queue by inserting a queue_job row with the `startAt` of `NOW()` and `endAt` of 
`perpetuity` which depending on the RDBMS should be set to the largest allowable DateTime.  I used `'9999-12-31'` here.

When A job is done, update the endAt date for that queue_job to be NOW.

**DDL**

```
 CREATE TABLE `job` (
     `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `name` VARCHAR(40),
     `createdAt` TIMESTAMP,
     CONSTRAINT `PK_job` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 )
 ENGINE=InnoDB;

 CREATE TABLE `queue` (
     `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `name` VARCHAR(40),
     `status` TINYINT UNSIGNED,
     CONSTRAINT `PK_queue` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 )
 ENGINE=InnoDB;

 CREATE TABLE `queue_job` (
     `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `queue_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED,
     `job_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED,
     `startAt` DATETIME,
     `endAt` DATETIME,
     CONSTRAINT `PK_queue_job` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 )
 ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Test Data and Example Queries**
  [A DB-Fiddle of this structure](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fSMpC8fG5faafuPhYoUP6W/0)

*Test Data*

```
 # Test Data
 INSERT INTO queue (name, status) VALUES ('Queue 1', 1), ('Queue 2', 1), ('Queue 3', 1), ('Queue 4', 0);
 INSERT INTO job (name) values ('Big Job');
 INSERT INTO job (name) values ('Little Job');
 INSERT INTO job (name) values ('Big Job');
 INSERT INTO job (name) values ('Little Job');
 INSERT INTO job (name) values ('Medium Job');
 INSERT INTO queue_job (queue_id, job_id, startAt, endAt) VALUES (2, 1, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 SECOND), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 SECOND));
INSERT INTO queue_job (queue_id, job_id, startAt, endAt) VALUES (3, 2, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 SECOND), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 SECOND));
 INSERT INTO queue_job (queue_id, job_id, startAt, endAt) VALUES (3, 3, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 MINUTE), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 MINUTE));

 INSERT INTO queue_job (queue_id, job_id, startAt, endAt) VALUES (2, 4, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 SECOND), '9999-12-31');
```

*Queries*

```
# Base tables
SELECT * FROM queue;
SELECT * FROM job;
SELECT * FROM queue_job;

# Jobs needing a reservation
SELECT j.*
FROM job j
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT j.id FROM queue_job qj WHERE qj.job_id = j.id);

 # Reserved Queues
 SELECT q.*, qj.*, j.* FROM queue q 
 JOIN queue_job qj ON (qj.queue_id = q.id)
 JOIN job j ON (j.id = qj.job_id)
 WHERE NOW() BETWEEN qj.startAt AND qj.endAt;

 # Historic Reservations
 SELECT q.*, qj.*, j.* FROM queue q 
 JOIN queue_job qj ON (qj.queue_id = q.id)
  JOIN job j ON (j.id = qj.job_id)
 WHERE NOW() > qj.endAt;

 # Available Queues is ALL active queues EXCEPT Reserved Queues
 SELECT q.* FROM queue q WHERE q.status = 1 AND q.id NOT IN
    (SELECT q.id 
     FROM queue q JOIN queue_job qj ON (qj.queue_id = q.id)
     WHERE NOW() BETWEEN qj.startAt AND qj.endAt);
```